# Div still has height:0px

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has content but it still has `height:0px;`, in the example you can see that "index-slideshow" has `height:0px;` and I need "position:absolute;" because the photos must be one above the other for a jQuery slideshow.

This div has contents but it hasn't any height. What's the problem?

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g2mhr0kw/1/)

```css
#index-slideshow {
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;
}
#index-slideshow > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 950px;
  max-width: 93%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="index-slideshow">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200">
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque suscipit magna ...

  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: There are two divs in your example. Which one (or both) have no height?

Comment: You can see that "index-slideshow" has height=0px

Answer (score 1):

It is because, the two images inside the `<div>` has `position: absolute;`. Absolutely positioned elements do not take up space.

See this example here:

```css
.border {border: 1px solid #999; margin-bottom: 100px;}
.abs {position: absolute; height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: #ccc;}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="abs">I am absolute!</div>
</div>
<div class="border">
  Hi
  <div class="abs">I am absolute!</div>
</div>
```

It is impossible to calculate the height of the absolutely positioned elements, just with CSS, because they are not in the layout.

Either make the `position` of the images as `static` or give a `min-height`.

Comment: Yeah that's good answer but I have to make a JQuary slideshow whit the immages so I need "position:absolute;" and min-height isn't good for responsive desing. You know another way?

Answer (score 0):

Your image div is over your wrap div.

Try one of these:

Remove:

```
position: relative;
```

JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g2mhr0kw/4/)

Or
Remove:

```
z-index: -1;
```

JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g2mhr0kw/3/).

Comment: No, I want thet the photos are on the top and the content are under the photos.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `position: absolute;` to `position: relative`.[Like this.](https://jsfiddle.net/g2mhr0kw/1/)

```
#index-slideshow > img {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width:100%;
max-width:100%;
margin:auto;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

}

The reason is a element will out normal flow when it has been **positioned**. Such as **fixed, absolute.** Out normal flow means that the elements will not take any space in the page, but still be visible.

Comment: I need "position: absolute;" because the imgs have to be one above the other